# Can't help the engine to choose the correct execution plan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, standard-edition

The stuff are pretty complex to share the original code (a lot of routines, a lot of tables), so I will try to summarize.

Environment:

- SQL Server 2016
- standard edition

Objects:

- wide table with the following columns:

  ```
  ID BIGINT PK IDENTITY
  Filter01 
  Filter02 
  Filter03 
  .. and many columns
  ```
- stored procedure returning visible `ID` from the given table depending on filter parameters
- the table has the following indexes:

  ```
  PK on ID
  NCI on Filter01 INCLUDE(Filter02, Filter03)
  NCI on Filter02 INCLUDE(Filter01, Filter03)
  ```

Basically, in the routine I am creating three temporary tables - each holding current filtering values and then join them with the main table. In some cases, `Filter02` values are not specified (so the join with this table is skipped) - the other tables are always joined. So, I have something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM maintable 
INNER JOIN #Filter01Values -- always exists
INNER JOIN #Filter02Values -- sometimes skipped
INNER JOIN #Filter03Values -- always exists
```

So, how the `IDs` are distributed - in 99% of the cases it will be best to filter by `Filter02Value` and I guess, because of this, the engine is using the `NCI on Filter02 INCLUDE(Filter01, Filter03)` index.

The issue is that in the rest 1% the query fails badly:

[image]

In green is the `Filter02` values table and you can see that filtering on this does not reduce the read rows at all. Then when the filtering by `Filter01` is done (in red) about 100 rows are returned.

So, this is happening only when the stored procedure is executed. If I execute its code with these parameters I nice execution plan:

[image]

In such case, the engine is filtering by `Filter01` first and `Filter02` third.

I am building and executing dynamic T-SQL statement and I add `OPTION(RECOMPILE) at` at the [end](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/2019/02/does-sp_executesql-with-recompile-actually-recompile-anything/), but it does not change anything. If I add `WITH RECOMPILE` on the stored procedure level, everything is fine.

Note, the values in the temporary tables for filtering are not populating in the dynamic-tsql statement. The tables are defined, populated and then the statement is built.

So, my questions are:

- is the engine building a new plan for my dynamic statement as I have `OPTION(recompile)` - if yes, why is wrong
- is the engine using the values populated in my filter02 temporary table to build the initial plan - maybe yes, that's why it is choosing the wrong plan
- using `recompile` on procedure level feels very hard/lazy fix - do you have any ideas how I can assist the engine further and skip this option - new indexes for examples (I have try a lot)

Comment: Instead of images, upload the actual plan xml to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question.

Comment: @DanGuzman This link does not work very well. I have never managed to make it work and always get - `The supplied XML is not a valid SQL Server query plan xml.` I will share the plan in other way.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RjhS6Wnr8n3DQ5D9QzX-ejPSsYPgKS2I?usp=sharing - take them from here - it's easy to get the slow query using plan explorer.

Comment: Try to first execute select SI.[SurveyInstanceID] 
from [dbo].[SurveyInstances] SI 
 inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_ProtoSurveysFiltered PSF 
  on SI.[ProtoSurveyID] = PSF.[ProtoSurveyID] 
where SI.[IsOkForExport] = 1 AND SI.[HoldExport] = 0 AND ( PSF.[AllowedBy] = 'C' ) and save this result into #tmp. The difference in your plans is in the join order in the INSERT INTO #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_SurveyInstances statement. Enforce the correct order by saving the result of the join above into temporary table

Answer (score 0):

From your plans I see the problem in this statement:

```
INSERT INTO #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_SurveyInstances ([SurveyInstanceID]) 
select SI.[SurveyInstanceID] 
from [dbo].[SurveyInstances] SI 
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_ProtoSurveysFiltered PSF 
        on SI.[ProtoSurveyID] = PSF.[ProtoSurveyID] 
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_ClientAccessStatusIDs CAS 
        on SI.[ClientAccessStatusID] = CAS.[ClientAccessStatusID] 
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_CampaignsFiltered CF 
        on SI.[CampaignID] = CF.[CampaignID] 
where SI.[IsOkForExport] = 1 AND SI.[HoldExport] = 0 AND ( PSF.[AllowedBy] = 'C' )
option(RECOMPILE)
```

There is no need in `recompile` here since there is no `parameters` at all, you have only constants here.
The difference in two plans is in the JOIN ORDER:

[image]

The correct join order is first

```
[dbo].[SurveyInstances] SI 
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_ProtoSurveysFiltered PSF 
        on SI.[ProtoSurveyID] = PSF.[ProtoSurveyID]
```

and then everything else, this join applies all the filters and produces only 104 rows that go to final resultset.

Your "slow" plan shows different join order:

```
[dbo].[SurveyInstances] SI 
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_CampaignsFiltered CF 
        on SI.[CampaignID] = CF.[CampaignID]
```

that produces 17 mln of rows.

You don't want this join order so your choices are to use `FORCE ORDER hint` or to simply save the result of the correct join to another `temp` table and then to `join` it with the rest of your query:

```
select SI.[SurveyInstanceID] 
into #si_psf
from [dbo].[SurveyInstances] SI 
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_ProtoSurveysFiltered PSF 
        on SI.[ProtoSurveyID] = PSF.[ProtoSurveyID] 
where SI.[IsOkForExport] = 1 AND SI.[HoldExport] = 0 AND ( PSF.[AllowedBy] = 'C' );


INSERT INTO #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_SurveyInstances ([SurveyInstanceID]) 
select SI.[SurveyInstanceID] 
from #si_psf SI
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_ClientAccessStatusIDs CAS 
        on SI.[ClientAccessStatusID] = CAS.[ClientAccessStatusID] 
    inner JOIN #Analysis_ClientAccess_SurveyInstances_CampaignsFiltered CF 
        on SI.[CampaignID] = CF.[CampaignID];
```

I suggest you to use the second method.

Comment: Yes, but I can rely that filtering by `#ProtoSurveysFiltered` will be always better and in many cases filtering by the `#CampaignsFiltered` is faster. I just want the engine to decide when to do each join. After all, I am giving to it indexes, statistics and rely that the better plan is going to be use.

Comment: And the most disappointing thing is that when I script the code, the engine is using the better plan, so it can do it :D I just want to help him to do it each time.